# Adding/removing char between outputs

Tags: java

I am on my homework and stucked. My output is like this 2, 4, 8, 
I just wanted to separate the numbers by comma and I used very simple code:

```
if (veri%4==0) System.out.print("4, ");
```

I dind't want to share hole code because I want to it myself but as I saw you can't help me. 
However my goal is that:
"Show me divider (only 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9) of numbers between 1-100 (NO Loops)"
So there are commas after all results. Can I add comma if there are more than 1 result or can I remove the last one?
And I wrote that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BolenleriBulmaOdevi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner komut=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("1 ile 100 arasında bir sayı giriniz: ");
        int veri=komut.nextInt();


        if (veri<1 || veri>100) {
            System.out.println("Hatalı veri girişi");
            }
            else if (veri==1) {
                System.out.println("1 girdiniz.");
            }
                else {
                    if (veri>=2) System.out.print(veri+" sayısının tek haneli bölenleri: ");
                    if (veri%2==0) System.out.print("2, ");
                    if (veri%3==0) System.out.print("3, ");
                    if (veri%4==0) System.out.print("4, ");
                    if (veri%5==0) System.out.print("5, ");
                    if (veri%6==0) System.out.print("6, ");
                    if (veri%7==0) System.out.print("7, ");
                    if (veri%8==0) System.out.print("8, ");
                    if (veri%9==0) System.out.print("9");
                }

    }

}
```

I think there are easier ways to do that.

I have solved.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BolenleriBulmaOdevi {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner komut=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("1 ile 100 arasında bir sayı giriniz: ");
    int veri=komut.nextInt();

    if (veri<1 || veri>100) 
        System.out.println("Hatalı veri girişi");

    if (veri==1) 
            System.out.println("1 girdiniz.");

                if (veri>=2) System.out.print(veri+" sayısının tek haneli bölenleri: ");
                if (veri%2==0) {
                    System.out.print("2");
                    if (veri%3==0 || veri%4==0 || veri%5==0 || veri%6==0 || veri%7==0|| veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%3==0) {
                    System.out.print("3");
                    if (veri%4==0 || veri%5==0 || veri%6==0 || veri%7==0|| veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%4==0) {
                    System.out.print("4");
                    if (veri%5==0 || veri%6==0 || veri%7==0|| veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%5==0) {
                    System.out.print("5");
                    if (veri%6==0 || veri%7==0|| veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%6==0) {
                    System.out.print("6");
                    if (veri%7==0|| veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%7==0) {
                    System.out.print("7");
                    if (veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%8==0) {
                    System.out.print("8");
                    if (veri%9==0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                }
                if (veri%9==0) System.out.print("9");
                if (veri%2!=0 && veri%3!=0 && veri%4!=0 && veri%5!=0 && 
                        veri%6!=0 && veri%7!=0 && veri%8!=0 && veri%9!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Asal sayı girdiniz. Bölenleri 1 ve "+veri);
                }



}
```

}

Comment: Please share more code, to see how you generate the numbers

Comment: You can refer to `StringJoiner` class in Java 8+, for reference https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-joiner

Comment: If you are trying to find power of 2 or something like that. Put a condition like if(num != required_no/condition) { System.out.print(","); System.out.println(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your separator in a variable, and print it first:

```
String separator = "";

while (...) {
  // ...

  if (veri%4==0) {
      System.out.print(separator);
      System.out.print("4");

      // Update for next time.
      separator = ", ";
  }

  // ...
}
```

---

About your edit: this isn't a good way of doing it; and it doesn't actually use what I suggested in this answer.

For example, this:

```
            if (veri%2==0) {
                System.out.print("2");
                if (veri%3==0 || veri%4==0 || veri%5==0 || veri%6==0 || veri%7==0|| veri%8==0 || veri%9==0)
                    System.out.print(", ");
            }
```

The nested if statement is verbose, error-prone (it's hard to see if it is correct without careful inspection), brittle (if you change the subsequent conditions, you have to remember to update it here too.

In general, this approach doesn't scale (what if you needed to do it for 100, 1000 etc conditions? What if the conditions under which things are printed are non-linear (i.e. some things are printed on further conditions or in loops)? What if the evaluation of the condition were expensive?).

Instead, do as I suggested:

```
            String separator = "";
            if (veri%2==0) {
                System.out.print(separator);
                System.out.print("2");
                separator = ", ";
            }
```

and the structure is identical for 3:

```
            if (veri%3==0) {
                System.out.print(separator);
                System.out.print("3");
                separator = ", ";
            }
```

And for all the other numbers; so you can rewrite it with a for loop:

```
            String separator = "";
            for (int d = 2; d <= 9; ++d) {
              if (veri%d==0) {
                  System.out.print(separator);
                  System.out.print(d);
                  separator = ", ";
              }
            }
```

And you can now rewrite that final condition:

```
if (separator.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Asal sayı girdiniz. Bölenleri 1 ve "+veri);
}
```

Comment: (You may find a for loop will help to reduce repetitive code).

Comment: Your edit bears very little relation to what I suggested.